# Anchor tag disabled color attribute not working?

Tags: html, css, angular, css-selectors

I did disabled anchor tag using component and need to show grey color as disabled link, but here the link is disabled, not turned into grey color. So user cant find whether it is disabled or not. could you please help me out?

HTML:

```
   <li class="nav-item" [class.disabled]="profile_flag">
       <a class="nav-link {{routeProfileStatus}}" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex=" 
            {{profile_flag?-1:0}}" (click)="gotoProfile()">My Profile</a>
   </li>
    <li class="nav-item" [class.disabled]="waitingRoom_flag">
        <a class="nav-link {{routeStatus}}"  style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex=" 
             {{waitingRoom_flag?-1:0}}" (click)="gotoDashboard()">Waiting Room</a>
     </li>
```

component:

```
 profile_flag : boolean = false;
  waitingRoom_flag : boolean = false;
```

css:

```
.disabled{
    color:grey;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:default;
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: You would need to apply the class to the link not to the list item

Answer (score 0):

Your `.disabled` class is added to the `li` tag, but you need to apply that rule to the `a`  inside `li`,

So use `.disabled > a` instead as a selector for that CSS rule.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `[class.disabled]` from `li` and use `ngClass` on top of a

```
<a class="nav-link {{routeStatus}}" [ngClass]="{ 'disabled' : waitingRoom_flag}" style="cursor: pointer;" tabindex="{{waitingRoom_flag?-1:0}}" (click)="gotoDashboard()">Waiting Room</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `disabled` class in the `a` tag instead of the `li` tag